# is the performance drop brought by using oop(specifically method calls) noticeable,say,in a low powered game console(arduboy)?

Tags: c, oop, methods, handheld

I am developing a programming language.In that,I am obliged to make a design decision.The decision, whether to implement methods as a functionality(which would render the language as Object Oriented.

My objective is to compile this language to a format compatible with handhelds,the likes of arduboy nano and fx.

Thus,I am wondering, whether using method calls will have any significant effect on the performance

I haven't tried anything as of now.I am uncertain for the methods to be considered for testing the performance,since I do not own an arduboy or a handheld with similar specs.
I have tried looking for opinion on the internet,but found none.

The official GitHub repo seems to be written in C.Thus,it isn't object oriented,owing to which it lacks the use of methods.However,this do not conclude that methods have any significant performance impact(i.e. drop in framerate)

Comment: What is the difference between a "function" and a "method"? If you look at e.g. C++, there's really no difference. A "method" is just a normal function, with the class-name as part of the name, and with an extra first argument that becomes the `this` pointer inside the member function. So if you already have "normal" non-member functions in your language, then you can use the same solution as C++ for your "methods". As for performance, then there will be no difference between "normal" and "method" functions.

Comment: Also please don't try to shoehorn in object-orientation (or other major changes like that) in an already existing language without major thoughts about it. If you already have a specification, a design and perhaps even a working compiler, it will be some major work to add such large changes. You might want to hold-on until you can create a new specification and a redesign for a version 2.0 of the language.

Comment: To be fully precise: In C++ there's nothing like a *'method'* (considering the wording of the standard), there only are functions and member functions...

Comment: If you have functions at all (and do not inline everything) they always come with an overhead, you need to load an address, jump in code to there and after completion return to the original address. More interesting is: Do you intend to implement *virtual* functions? This makes *overriding* functions and thus polymorphism possible at all, a core feature of OOP (without, I wouldn't speak of, then your member functions are just syntactic sugar...).

Comment: If functions imply indirection (loading addresses first) then *virtual* functions come with double indirection (first load the v-table, lookup the true function address there and then load this one)...

Comment: By the way: C per se doesn't support object orientation as a language feature – this doesn't mean that you cannot have object orientation in C at all, e.g. you can implement an equivalent to v-tables on your own using function pointers and that way realise polymorphism. What you don't get in any way, though, is destructors (well, you can write destructing functions, but don't get the automatic call of, at least), thus you cannot rely on RAII either...

Comment: IIRC the ATMega32U4 is a quite old-school processor and it does *not* have the go-faster features that are broken by things like indirect calls.

Answer (score 0):

> I am developing a programming language.

As a prerequisite to doing so, it would perhaps be advisable to study existing programming languages like C and C++ and how they translate source code to machine code.

> whether to implement methods as a functionality(which would render the language as Object Oriented.

There is no such thing as "object oriented languages", there are just languages with more or less support for OO features. Object orientation is a way to design programs. Your program does not automatically turn object-oriented because you use a certain language.

The pillars of fundamental OO are private encapsulation, autonomous objects and inheritance/polymorphism. None of these *require* member functions as such, although they are obviously very handy to have. As as RAII with constructors/destructors, but that's still no *requirement* for OO design.

> whether using method calls will have any significant effect on the performance

That depends on the context. A plain `static` C++ object does not come (should not) with additional overhead for calling a member function, compared to an ordinary function. The only extra overhead that you might get from such objects is the default constructor getting called by the CRT.

In a design using inheritance/polymorphism, you'll need vtables in between no matter language, and these come with a slight memory and function call overhead. They might also block function inlining in some situations. I wouldn't call it a "significant" effect on performance, but it is extra overhead.

Generally one stayed clear of such things in tiny legacy microcontrollers like ATMega 8-bitters, mainly because RAM was very tight. Writing C code for such MCUs was a novel thing even - in the 1990s the majority of these programs were written in assembler and the general switch to C happened in the early 2000s, around the time when Arduino was released. Some 5 to 10 years later, 8-bitters had mostly gotten phased out from new designs.

> The official GitHub repo seems to be written in C.Thus,it isn't object oriented

This isn't necessarily true. It is perfectly possible to write OO programs in C, just like it is common to not write OO programs in C++ - the keyword `class` doesn't magically turn the program design OO.

However, 8 bit microcontroller programming is/was usually done with a minimum of abstraction layers, because these MCUs were so dreadfully slow. "Framerate" is probably not a thing on anything running from an 8-bitter; these do not typically have DMA even.